# SVG animate accordion two letter word into longer word?

Tags: inkscape, text, svg, animation, linux

Using a plain-text editor, preferably, or Inkscape, are there any good tutorials on taking two letters and inserting more letters between them, and animating it so that the two letters expand outward like an accordion, as the middle fills in?

Comment: That is not a graphic design issue. That is a JavaScript issue. Search things like https://www.google.com/search?q=JavaScripts+animate+text

Comment: Hi.  Inkscape is not animation software.  It has no animation features.